# Five Columns to a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following data

```
+--------+
| orders |
+--------+
| S1     |
| S2     |
| S3     |
| S4     |
| S5     |
| S6     |
| S7     |
| S8     |
| S9     |
| S10    |
| S11    |
| S12    |
+--------+
```

I am required to return the result as follows - fit five rows in one column:

```
+-----------------+
|     Orders      |
+-----------------+
| S1,S2,S3,S4,S5  |
| S6,S7,S8,S9,S10 |
| S11,S12         |
+-----------------+
```

There is nothing to group on or segregate these into rows. So I assigned a row_number and did mod 5 on the row_number. It almost works, but  not quite.

Here is what I have tried:

```
;with mycte as (
select
'S1' as orders
union all select
'S2'
union all select
'S3'
union all select
'S4'
union all select
'S5'
union all select
'S6'
union all select
'S7'
union all select
'S8'
union all select
'S9'
union all select
'S10'
union all select
'S11'
union all select
'S12'
)
,mycte2 as (
Select 
orders
,ROW_NUMBER() over( order by orders) %5 as rownum 
from mycte
)
select distinct
 STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + mycte2.orders
            FROM mycte2
            where t1.rownum= mycte2.rownum
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') orders 
, rownum
 from mycte2 t1
```

the result is :

```
+-----------+--------+
|  orders   | rownum |
+-----------+--------+
| S1,S3,S8  |      1 |
| S10,S4,S9 |      2 |
| S11,S5    |      3 |
| S12,S6    |      4 |
| S2,S7     |      0 |
+-----------+--------+
```

Can someone please show me how to get to my desired result?

Comment: Any reason why it should be done in the database layer?

Comment: @PM77-1 The output is then presented to the end user for further consumption.. The user wants 5 orders per line to fit with their existing solution. (excel)

Comment: You need to extract the number value from the orders (this would be much easier if you just entered the numbers by themselves or additionally but if you don't it's a simple matter of something like `cast(substring(orders, 2, len(orders)) as int)` then order by that DIVIDED by 5 (not mod 5) to split the groups. Be sure to -1 from the row number though since 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 each divide into 5 0 times... So essentially `(ROW_NUMBER() over( order by cast(substring(orders, 2, len(orders)) as int)) - 1) / 5 as rownum `.

Comment: You didn't answer the question.  Why do you want SQL solution?  Why not to do it in a presentations layer?

Comment: @PM77-1 presentation is via SSRS.. if you have a solution for the same via SSRS happy to look that way as well.

Comment: @ZLK thank you so much.. this worked! If you make that your answer, I'll accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([orders] varchar(3));

INSERT INTO T
    ([orders])
VALUES
    ('S1'),
    ('S2'),
    ('S3'),
    ('S4'),
    ('S5'),
    ('S6'),
    ('S7'),
    ('S8'),
    ('S9'),
    ('S10'),
    ('S11'),
    ('S12');

WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Orders,
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LEN(Orders)) - 1) / 5 RN
  FROM T
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(Orders, ',')
FROM CTE
GROUP BY RN
ORDER BY RN;
```

OR

```
SELECT STUFF(
              (
                SELECT ',' + Orders
                FROM CTE
                WHERE RN = TT.RN
                FOR XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) Orders
FROM CTE TT
GROUP BY RN
ORDER BY RN;
```

> You can use `(SELECT 1)` instead of `LEN(Orders)`

**Returns:**

```
+-----------------+
|     Orders      |
+-----------------+
| S1,S2,S3,S4,S5  |
| S6,S7,S8,S9,S10 |
| S11,S12         |
+-----------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=505a2003aa34345f4d074d30938adfa2)**

Comment: NTILE doesn't seem like an appropriate solution here (or anywhere for that matter, but that's a separate subject). The OP seems to require splitting the orders into groups of 5. NTILE is for splitting a result set into X groups.

Comment: Thanks @Sami.. ZLK proposed the same solution in his comments and it works.. and string_agg works only for 2017 onwards.