# How to show one field value in matrix form in ssrs

Tags: matrix, reporting-services

How to show one field value in matrix form in ssrs like RecordId column
this should be show like 1 2 3 and 
                         4 5 6 in another row
                         7 8 9 in another row
                         10 11 12 in another row
this way I want to show.

Comment: You may find this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57078346/10755978) of mine useful for this requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I loop records so that 2 records per row one on left and other on right, is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57076070/how-can-i-loop-records-so-that-2-records-per-row-one-on-left-and-other-on-right)

Comment: you may want to look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715205/sql-server-2016-five-column-to-single-row